# Why is any arbitrary motion of a coupled oscillator writable as a linear combination of its normal modes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

Consider the following example of a coupled oscillator. Let two identical pendulums, each of length $\ell$ and mass $m$ be connected by a spring of force constant $k$. The system has two normal modes with frequencies $\omega_1=\sqrt{g/\ell}$ and $\omega_2=\sqrt{(g/\ell)+(2k/m)}$.

Why is any arbitrary motion of this coupled oscillator writable as a linear combination of the two normal modes? I mean how does the conclusion follow?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266889/eigenvalue-equation-for-kinetic-and-potential-energy?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478923/why-are-all-solutions-to-this-system-of-pendulum-differential-equations-a-linear?rq=1

Comment: Because it's a system of *linear* differential equations is the simplest explanation.

Comment: This is the *spectral theorem* isn't it?